# How do I grab my google custom search input in my react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, google-custom-search

I'm using Google custom search in my React application:

http://www.assertivesolutions.ca

I'd like to change the default placeholder "Custom Search" to say something else. There doesn't seem to be a way to do this with CSS, so I'm trying to grab it in Javascript. I have this in the componentDidMount() hook:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.methodType === 'search') {
        const searchInput = document.querySelector('#gsc-i-id1');
        console.log('componentDidUpdate: ', searchInput);
    }
}
```

It prints out null to the console, meaning that it didn't grab anything from the DOM.

I'm not sure how Google custom search injects the search bar onto the page, but it seems to be asynchronous. Therefore, I can't rely on it being ready by the time componentDidMount() fires. But as far as I know, componentDidMount is the last hook that fires on page load.

So my question is: how do I know when the Google custom search is ready (i.e. available in the DOM)? And is there any kind of hook I can use to grab it?

Thanks.

Here is the full component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../../App.scss';
import './ContactMethod.scss';
// eslint-disable-next-line
import callUsIcon from '../../assets/images/call-us-icon.png';

class ContactMethod extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.methodType === 'search') {
        const searchInput = document.querySelector('#gsc-i-id1');
        console.log('componentDidUpdate: ', searchInput);
    }
}

render() {
    // Figure out which contact method this is:
    let methodTypeName = '';
    let methodTypeValue = '';
    let icon = '';
    switch (this.props.methodType) {
        case 'phone':
            methodTypeName = 'Call Us';
            methodTypeValue = '403-999-4951';
            icon = require('../../assets/images/call-us-icon.png');
            break;
        case 'email':
            methodTypeName = 'Email Us';
            methodTypeValue = 'support@assertivesolutions.ca';
            icon = require('../../assets/images/email-us-icon.png');
            break;
        case 'search':
            methodTypeName = 'Search';
            methodTypeValue = 'Enter search here...';
            icon = require('../../assets/images/search-icon.png');
            break;
        // need default case
    }

    // If this is search, we want an input field:
    var valueElement = <span className="contact-method-value">{ methodTypeValue }</span>;
    if (this.props.methodType === 'search') {
        valueElement = <div className="gcse-search" /> // <-- here
    }

    // Return the component:
    return (
        <div className="contact-method flex-row-space-between">
            <div className="flex-column-center">
                <img src={ icon } alt="{ icon }" />
            </div>
            <div className="name-and-value flex-column-space-around">
                <span className="contact-method-name">{ methodTypeName }</span>
                { valueElement } // <-- and here
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default ContactMethod;
```

Comment: Would you show us how did you implement it in your app?

Comment: I edited my post with more code. I marked the points of interest with // <-- here